# byobu using invalid 'readlink -f' option on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, unix

I just installed byobu on mountain lion by running

```
./configure  
make  
make install
```

The install seems good. But byobu is trying to use 'readlink -f' which is an illegal option with OS X and any other BSD system (I think).

Is there any kind of hack I can do to get around this?

Comment: [How can I get the behavior of GNU's readlink -f on a Mac? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055671/how-can-i-get-the-behavior-of-gnus-readlink-f-on-a-mac)

Answer (score 2):

If you lack `readlink -f` functionality, the coreutils and tmux are likely the missing dependencies. Please edit your question if you have them installed and this doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: i have both tmux and coreutils and i still get the same issue ... it should be using greadlink not readlink on osx